# Swift NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData doesn't handle empty Data

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a data downloader class that downloads data from mySQL server.
The problem I am having is when the result is null - the app crashes with error message

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' (0x105548918) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x105549c00).

```
class userDetailsDownloader: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

  weak var delegate: getUserDetails!
  var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

  func downloadUserDetails(userEmail: String) {

    let urlPath: String = "http://intouchmobile.co/phpscripts/getuserpassword.php?email=\(userEmail)"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var session: NSURLSession!
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration() //defaultSessionConfiguration()
    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)
    task.resume()
  }

  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.data.appendData(data);

  }

  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil
    {
        print("Failed to get password")
    }
    else
    {
        self.parseJSON()
        print("Password Received")
    }

  }
  func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var password: String!
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!


    do{
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The app crashes _where_? On what line?

Comment: It crashes on the jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData

Comment: Basically don't use the mutable Foundation collection types in Swift, because they are not related to the Swift native types and cannot be bridged nor casted. Use the native types instead. With `var` you get mutability for free.

Comment: @vadian good advice as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't say `as! NSMutableArray`. The term `as!` *means* "crash me", so you can hardly be surprised when you do crash. Say `as? NSMutableArray`. Test the result for `nil`. If it is `nil`, stop.

```
if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableArray {
    self.jsonResult = jsonResult
}
```

You may still have problems because this is never going to be a mutable array; it's just an array. So you might have to change it to:

```
if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSArray {
    self.jsonResult = NSMutableArray(array: jsonResult)
}
```

(But, as vadian has said in a comment, it would be even better if you could abandon use of NSArray and NSMutableArray and use Swift types instead.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The JSON returns empty brackets [], so it is 5 bytes long. Can I count that it will always be ~5 and add this condition - if data.length > 5?

Comment: I decided I didn't like my answer so I changed it. The problem is the `as!`. This is quite normal...

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I needed. The 2nd option worked and it now provides an array I can count. THANKS a LOT!!

Comment: I'm very glad this worked! But you should still be listening to vadian's advice... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data) {
   //your do catch
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: This came back as invalid data in both cases - valid JSON and empty one unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It came back with invalid JSON despite being a valid JSON your put into the function? That is hard to believe, but your problem was solved so it kind of doesn't matter :D.